# how to select only 1 unique data when joining two tables, if the table structure is one to many?

Tags: sql, oracle

i am using an oracle database, i have two tables.

table A
primary key = productid

table B 
references productid of table A

primary key = imageid

flow:

each product should have 4 images stored in the table B (mandatory)

problem:

there are some products that has only 2 or sometimes 3 or sometimes 1 image only
despite of the fact that the 4 images rule is mandatory based from code level.

Question:

how to count unique number of products that has images in table b?Because, if I do

`select count(*) from tableA join tableB on tableA.productid = tableB.productid`

the result is double, because it's a one to many...as in , one product has many images.
So let's say `productID = 12345` has `4 images` in `table B`, once I ran my query, the result is 4 , when i want to only get 1...so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT TableA.productid)
FROM   TableA 
JOIN   TableB ON TableA.productid = TableB.productid;
```

Comment: Thanks. this answer is my first answer and first accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Do a sub query with where exists

```
select count(*) from tableA 
where exists (select 1 from tableB where tableA.productid = tableB.productid)
```

Comment: By the way, this is called semi join. According to Oracle Documentation - 

A semijoin returns rows that match an EXISTS subquery without duplicating rows from the left side of the predicate when multiple rows on the right side satisfy the criteria of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(    
select A.productId from tableA A join tableB B on A.productid = B.productid
    GROUP BY A.productId
    HAVING COUNT(B.imageId) > 1 ) T
```